# Set IsFocused property from the code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The `IsFocused` property is read-only and it can't be directly manipulated. However I need to change this value upon Clicking a button in reverse way:

```
private Boolean isClicked = false;
private void Toggle_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    if (isClicked) {
         set IsFocued false;
    }
    else {
      set IsFocued True;
    }
    isCLicked = !isCLicked;
}
```

The reason why I wanna do such thing at all is that I wanna make a toggle button, and my resources are Embedded in code and I do not want to convert then to Base64 and load them that way for the sake of code clarity because I find that long sequence kindda ugly. But what is my idea then, here it is:

```
                <Button Name="Toggle" Click="Toggle_Click" Cursor="Hand" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="46">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Off.png" Stretch="Uniform"></ImageBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/On.png" Stretch="Uniform"></ImageBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

So when the button is clicked, the next time it will be clicked, the value of IsFocused` will be false rather than true. Any help on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: Try the **FocusManager.SetFocusedElement** Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also useful is this article - **Focus Overview** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor: what are these two parameters, `DependencyObject element`, `IInputElement value` and what should go in there?

Comment: @Gusdor: `FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(Toggle, true);` this method does not work

Comment: @Gusdor: Thanks figured it out

Comment: @weston: Change image on focus, and change image on focus again based on a boolean value

Comment: Why are you trying to use the IsFocused property for a toggle state?  Who would want focus to move to a different element when they click a toggle button?

Comment: @Blam: If you read the XAML code you will see why, anyways that is because of what I explained in the question, wanna change the ON OFF images and have embeded resources and don't wanna use BASE64 to load them, BTW I answered my own question you cann have a look.

Comment: I read your xml.  If you read my comment why that property?  It is read only property and not designed to be used for that.  When you click to another element you do know the IsFocued will be set to false?

Comment: @Blam: There's no other focusable element in my from.

Comment: Only works with if there are no other focusable elements is a bit limiting.   I asked a simple question  "Why are you trying to use the IsFocused property for a toggle state?"  Using that property has consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
private Boolean isClicked = false;
private void Toggle_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    if (isClicked) {
     FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, Toggle);
    }
    else {
       FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, null);
    }
    isCLicked = !isCLicked;
}
```

Comment: You do know IsFocused will change to false when you click on another element?

Comment: @Blam: What if there is no other focusable element? would it change then? and what to do in that case?

Comment: Fine you have a solution that works if there is only one focusable element.  That is limiting.  Only focusable element was not in the question.  Most people would not think a button would be the only focusable element.

Answer (score 0):

That could be reduced even further to:

```
private Boolean isClicked = false;
private void Toggle_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, isClicked ? Toggle : null);
    isCLicked = !isCLicked;
}
```