# How to Press a button in the view using ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and I understand that the ViewModel doesn't have any communication with View. I am trying to follow MVVM pattern in my application and I would like to press a button in the View using ViewModel. eg: After a successful login I want to show a specific grid in the view. This can also be done by pressing the 'X' button'. When the 'X' button has focus it will show the following grid.

```
        ..<Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=X}"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 <Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>..
```

Given the situation, How can I get this grid to be displayed using the ViewModel?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'press' a button by executing the `Command` bound to the button (a command of the `ICommand` type). This would not give any visual indication the button was pressed but would have the same effect in the background. You could also bound a property to the `IsFocused` property of the grid toggle the visibility via changing the property in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you mean to say IsFocused property of the button? If it is there is not IsFocused property on the button. I tried using Focusable and it does not work. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes I mean `IsFocused` of the button. When you change the value, the change ViewModel, it will trigger you data trigger on the grid, since it's bound to the `IsFocused` of the 'X' button. Focusable however, is just a property that tells you if an element can be focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the IsFocused property of the button to a property on your viewmodel. Than once the user has logged in successfully, set the IsFocused property in the viewmodel to the appropriate value.

In MVVM, ViewModel is the state of the View. You statement, "ViewModel doesn't have any communication with View" is incorrect. The View and ViewModel 'talk' via bindings. Bindings engine built into WPF is extremely powerful, not only does it let you bind to different elements in your visual tree but also to public properties on the DataContext.

See the related question for how to set the IsFocused property from code - 
[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630753/set-isfocused-property-from-the-code/)

Hope that helps.